# Error while opening dbeaver.. "See the log file .dbeaver/.metadata/.log

Tags: java, ubuntu-14.04, dbeaver

dbeaver was working fine in my system.But,suddenly it is giving an error  "See the log file /home/system/.dbeaver/.metadata/.log". Please,can someone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you actually tried checking the logfile?

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i check the logfile??

Comment: Hm? `less /home/system/.dbeaver/.metadata/.log`? Does not work for some reason, or what is wrong?

Comment: there is no logfile in folder of dbeaver when i try to open using terminal and no metadata file also.When i try to open dbeaver it is giving error "to see the log file"

Comment: `.metadata` is a folder. It is hidden. Just like the `.log` file. I am sorry but if you are unable to perform basic file operations on your own system, then there is no way to help you.

Comment: Sure Gergely Basco, 'cos every computer user is a Java expert!!   Get off your high-horse!!      Bhagyashree O, any luck on getting it up and running? as I don't have hours to diagnose ANOTHER java stack.   (Thanks Oracle for killing Java and wasting everybody's time!!)

Comment: That might also happen if you are updating the DBeaver from an almost very old version to a new one. Instead of updating, just uninstall the old one completely once, and then install the new version.

Answer (score 1):

It might be the case that jdk is changed. Try moving the jdk if so from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines to another location. This happened with me when I installed jdk11 and moving it, resolved my issue.